# Getting a runtime error with Angular material MatDefs

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am getting this error when I run my angular code...

> NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatRowDef -> TemplateRef]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatRowDef -> TemplateRef]:

I tried a bit of googling and the only solutions i found did't work. Anywas, here is the code that this problem is coming from. 
I did import all the dependencies in a different folder, so if you need that let me know.
Thanks for the help!

**Typescript:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../data/data.service';
import {Post} from '../Post';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
  }

  displayedColumns = ['date_posted', 'title', 'category', 'delete'];
  dataSource = new PostDataSource(this.dataService);
}  

export class PostDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.dataService.getData();
  }

  disconnect() {
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<br>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="container">
        <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayout.gt-md="row"  fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" class="content">
            <div class="blocks">
                <button button="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary">
                    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> Add Post
                </button>
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="container">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="content">
      <mat-card class="card" >
        <mat-card-title fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
          <h3>Recent Posts</h3>
        </mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content>
            <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
                <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="date_posted">
                  <mat-header-cell matHeaderCellDef> Date Posted </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date_posted  | date: 'd/M/y'}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
                    <mat-header-cell matHeaderCellDef> Title </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
                    <mat-header-cell matHeaderCellDef> Category </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell matCellDef="let element"> {{element.category}} </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
                    <mat-header-cell matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell matCellDef="let element">
                      <a
                          type="button">
                        <mat-icon class="icon">delete</mat-icon>
                      </a>
                    </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>
                  <mat-header-row matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                  <mat-row matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
                </mat-table>
              </div>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer!
I looked up examples of other people that use MatDef's and some of them had little *. I put * at the start of all my mats and it fixed it.